# Is it possible to run hook_field_presave after hook_entity_presave?

Tags: location

I am using Drupal 7. I use hook_entity_presave() to manipulate geofield data. The geofield module has a hook_field_presave() function, that calculates various data for the field. 
My problem is, that [hook_field_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7) runs before hook_entity_presave(), so my data is not available to process. I am looking at [hook_module_implementations_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7), but it seems that it does not care about hook_field_presave(), and even if it would know about this hook, I still don't know how to change the execution order of two different hooks. Any idea how to solve this? I could just copy the logic of geofield_field_presave(), but that is not a nice solution.

Comment: Can you not do your code in hook_field_presave() instead of hook_entity_presave()? hook_module_implements_alter() only help with order within the same hook so it can't help across different hooks.

Comment: Also remember that it isn't just geofield_field_presave() you have to worry about. You have to make sure your solution will work with any other module that implements hook_field_presave().

Comment: Well as I understood, hook_field_presave() is for the fields that a module defines, and since my module does not define any fields, I haven't tried using this hook. In contrast, geofield defines geofield, so it uses hook_field_presave(). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: And even if I were using hook_field_presave(), how do I set execution order, since it does not show up as a hook in hook_module_implements_alter()? I have also thought of another very ugly solution, calling geofield_field_presave() from my module with parameters properly set. I have never seen or heard of anything like this though, does it kill kittens? :)

Comment: I have solved my problem calling geofield_compute_values() in my hook_entity_presave function, but I am still curious whether it is possible to set execution order of hook_field_presave().

Comment: Oh yeah whoops, hook_field_presave() is not a proper hook. Kind of annoying when there are things like this that go against the way everything else works. It really shouldn't be called a hook, it's more of a callback.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to get your code in before that hook_field_presave() because there are no hooks between the start of the save action and hook_field_presave() and you cannot implement hook_field_presave() as you would any other hook.